# Unable to deploy simple web bundle using Spring DM on glassfish 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-dm

I am new to OSGI and Spring DM. I am trying to deploy a simple Hello World wen application as war on **Glassfish 3.1**
 but facing some serios issues. 
I have 3 non-web OSGI bundles:

```
1. helloworld-model.jar
2. helloworld-service.jar
3. helloworld-servicedao.jar
```

And one web bundle helloworld-web.war. I am using Glassfish asadmin "deploy --type=osgi .jar/war" to deploy my osgi bundles. Delpoyment completes successfully there is no error in server.log and even all the four applications are displayed in web based admin console. But I am not able to access my web application, which I access it using http and 8080 port, I get 404, which means my application is not available. I used standard way of defining MANIFEST.MF for all the bundles and also defined required elements in my web.xml.

Can someone help me to investigate the rootcause of this issue. Also if someone can provide basic steps to create and deploy the web bundle on Glassfish, it would be highly appreciated. I browsed through lot of web, but could not find one single place which structly defines all the required steps.